# How to read ratings from play store ratings of my app using https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3

Tags: python, android, google-api, google-play

I can read the play store reviews using below api:

```
GET https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/{packageName}/reviews
```

I also want to download the ratings. I am unable to find it in the documentation. is there any way I can download ratings as well?

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no built-in REST API to get the current overall star rating of an app or latest ratings without reviews.
The available APIs are described here: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest

To download ratings you need to access Google Play Console and manually download CSV files

Alternatively if you can enable cloud reports (from Google Cloud Storage), you can download monthly report using their custom API, like this one: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870?hl=en#zippy=%2Cratings